# Unable to load class when using @Embedded property in @MappedSuperClass - Wildfly Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss, wildfly

I would like to have JPA models like they are described in code snippets.

When I try to add @Embedded property of Licence class into my "abstract mapped super class Employee" I got an error pasted below. If I remove Licenced property from my Employee class everything is working fine.

Class examples are all placed in the same package:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity {

    private Instant tsCreated;
    private Instant tsModified;

}

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Employee extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(name="first_name", nullable = false)
    private String firstname;

    @Column(name = "last_name", nullable = false)
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private String email;

    @Embedded
    private Licence licence;   // here is the issue

}

@Entity
@Table(name="developer")
public class Developer extends Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "age")
    private int age;

}

@Embeddable
public class Licence {

    private String licence;

    @Column(name = "licence_number")
    private int licenceNumber;

    public Licence() {}

}
```

my persitence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd"
             version="2.2">
    <persistence-unit name="default">
        <description>Error debugging example hibernate jpa wildfly.</description>
        <jta-data-source>java:/PostgresDS</jta-data-source>

        <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.lock.timeout" value="60"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.query.timeout" value="60"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
            <property name="hibernate.enhancer.enableDirtyTracking" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.enhancer.enableLazyInitialization" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

console error

```
13:29:50,516 INFO  [org.hibernate.bytecode.enhance.spi.Enhancer] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 83) Enhancing [com.example.wildflyhibernatedemo.Developer] as Entity
13:29:50,569 WARN  [org.jboss.modules.define] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 83) Failed to define class com.example.wildflyhibernatedemo.Developer in Module "deployment.wildfly-hibernate-demo-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Failed to link com/example/wildflyhibernatedemo/Developer (Module "deployment.wildfly-hibernate-demo-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war" from Service Module Loader): WFLYJPA0073: Transformation of class com/example/wildflyhibernatedemo/Developer failed
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:468)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:276)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:79)
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:753)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:192)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
        at org.hibernate@5.3.24.Final//org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(AggregatedClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:587)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467)
        at org.hibernate@5.3.24.Final//org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:131)
        at org.hibernate@5.3.24.Final//org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.<init>(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:105)
        at org.hibernate@5.3.24.Final//org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.<init>(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:156)
        at org.hibernate@5.3.24.Final//org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:150)
        at org.hibernate@5.3.24.Final//org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1215)
        at org.hibernate@5.3.24.Final//org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1246)
        at org.hibernate.jipijapa-hibernate5-3@26.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate5.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:44)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa@26.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:171)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa@26.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:129)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
        at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@1.18.3.Final//org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:664)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa@26.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:214)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)

13:29:50,572 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 83) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."wildfly-hibernate-demo-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war#default": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."wildfly-hibernate-demo-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war#default": org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [com.example.wildflyhibernatedemo.Developer]
        at org.jboss.as.jpa@26.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:199)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa@26.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:129)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
        at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@1.18.3.Final//org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:664)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa@26.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:214)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [com.example.wildflyhibernatedemo.Developer]
        at org.hibernate@5.3.24.Final//org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:134)
        at org.hibernate@5.3.24.Final//org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.<init>(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:105)
        at org.hibernate@5.3.24.Final//org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.<init>(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:156)
        at org.hibernate@5.3.24.Final//org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:150)
        at org.hibernate@5.3.24.Final//org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1215)
        at org.hibernate@5.3.24.Final//org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1246)
        at org.hibernate.jipijapa-hibernate5-3@26.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate5.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:44)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa@26.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:171)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : com.example.wildflyhibernatedemo.Developer
        at org.hibernate@5.3.24.Final//org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(AggregatedClassLoader.java:210)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:587)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467)
        at org.hibernate@5.3.24.Final//org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:131)
        ... 17 more
```

I'm deploying this project to wildfly26.0.1-final

my pom.xml configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-hibernate-demo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>wildfly-hibernate-demo</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <junit.version>5.8.2</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.SP1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I'm looking for any kind of comment or explanation of what can be wrong, the same example is working if I try to build and run with Spring-boot.